# VS 2010 Can't connect projects in AzureDevops server 2019

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, azure-devops, azure-devops-server-2019

VS 2010 connects to DevOps 2019 inhouse server, it lists all the projects properly but when you try to connect to a project it gets the latest and goes offline. This is only happening in VS 2010. VS 2015, 2017 and 2019 works perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those who are facing the above issue when connecting from Visual Studio 2010 with Devops server 2019, please install the following.

Service Pack 1 for Visual Studio 2010
Visual Studio 2010 SP1 Team Foundation Server [Compatibility GDR](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29082)

After installing and restarting the machine, Above issue will resolve.

Comment: Very appreciate this solution shared here. You can accept this answer, thus other SO users can refer yo this correct answer:-)